# $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \mu}$ where $\psi$ is the solution of $\ddot{x}+\tanh{(2\dot{x}+x)}=\mu e^t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am asked to find $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \mu}(t, t_0, x_0, \dot{x}_0, µ) \ $at the point$ \ (t, t_0, x_0, \dot{x}_0, µ) = (t, 0, 0, 0, 0)$ where $\psi$ is the solution of   $\ddot{x}+\tanh{(2\dot{x}+x)}=\mu e^t \ $.

I transformed the equation into
$$
\begin{cases}
& \dot{x}_1=x_2 \newline
& \dot{x}_2=-\tanh{(2x_2+x_1)}+\mu e^t
\end{cases}
$$
So $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \mu}$ is the solution of $\dot{X}=AX+b(t)$, $X(0)=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \newline
0
\end{pmatrix}
$
where $A(t)=Df = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\newline
-\frac{1}{cosh^2{(2x_2+x_1)}} & -\frac{2}{cosh^2{(2x_2+x_1)}}
\end{pmatrix}
$ evaluated in a solution of the system (with $\mu = 0$ in this case) but I don't know how to get a solution (I didn't see any similar problem in class before).

How can i get a solution? Or is there any other way to find the partial derivative?

Comment: You should recognize that you are ask to compute the almost trivial case, as you have $\mu=0$ and $\psi=0$, and close to that solution the linear terms are $\ddot x+2\dot x+x=e^t$ with $\psi=0+\mu x+O(\mu^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account the specific data given in the task, the basis solution is for $\mu=0$ with $x(0)=\dot x(0)=0$, which puts the IVP into a stationary point, so that the solution is constant zero.

At this point the task is the same as computing the first-order perturbation for $\mu\approx 0$ where $x=x_0+\mu x_1+...=\mu x_1+O(\mu^2)$. The perturbation equation determining $x_1$, which is $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\mu}$ in the original notation, is thus
$$
\ddot x_1+2\dot x_1+x_1=e^t\iff \frac{d^2}{dt^2}(e^tx_1)=e^{2t}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Calling $\psi = (x_1,x_2)^{\dagger}$ we have

$$
\dot\psi = f(\psi,\mu,t)
$$

and

$$
\frac{\partial \dot\psi}{\partial\mu}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\psi}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial\mu}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mu}
$$

with

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\psi}=\left(\matrix{0&1\\ -\cosh^{-2}(2\psi_2+\psi_1)&-2\cosh^{-2}(2\psi_2+\psi_1)}\right),\ \ \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\mu}=\left(\matrix{0\\ e^t}\right) \ \ \text{if $\mu \ne 0$}\ \ \text{otherwise}\ \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\mu}=\left(\matrix{0\\ 0}\right) 
$$

so we need to solve simultaneously

$$
\cases{
\dot\psi = f(\psi,\mu,t)\\
\frac{\partial \dot\psi}{\partial\mu}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial\psi}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial\mu}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mu}
}
$$

thus obtaining $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial\mu}$ for a particular $\mu_0$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script to proceed with those calculations

```
tmax = 2;
f = {x2[t], -Tanh[2 x2[t] + x1[t]] + mu E^t};
ode1 = Thread[{x1'[t], x2'[t]} == f];
dfdx = Grad[f, {x1[t], x2[t]}];
dfdmu = D[f, mu];
ode2 = Thread[{x1mu'[t], x2mu'[t]} == dfdx.{x1mu[t], x2mu[t]} + dfdmu];
odes = Join[ode1, ode2] /. {mu -> 0.1};
cinits = {x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, x1mu[0] == 0, x2mu[0] == 0};
odes0 = Join[odes, cinits];
sol = NDSolve[odes0, {x1, x2, x1mu, x2mu}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x1mu[t], x2mu[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}]
```